# If $ \mathbf {nul} [T]_B^C = \{0\}$, then $T$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space, $\dim V = \dim W = n$, let $T : V \to W$ be a linear transformation,
and let $B, C$ be ordered bases for $V, W$, respectively. If $\mathbf {nul} [T]_B^C = \{0\}$, then $T$ is an isomorphism.

---

So I want to show that the kernel is trivial.

Let $\Bbb v \in V$, $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ a basis for $V$, then $\Bbb v = a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n$ for some $a_1,\ldots,a_n \in \Bbb R$.

We can write $[T(\Bbb v)]_C=[T]_B^C[\Bbb v]_B~~$ so $~~[T(\Bbb v)]_C = [T]_B^C \begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\ 
\vdots \\ 
a_n
\end{bmatrix}$

From here I stuck... Appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: If $v$ is in the kernel of $T$, then $[T(v)]_C = \ldots$

Comment: @azif00 $= 0$ of course, but why is $v$ in the kernel? I think that I miss something here...

Comment: If you pick $v \in \ker T$ and you show $v = 0$, this means that $\ker T$ is trivial, as you want to prove. By the way, in this case, $[T(v)]_C$ is the column vector of zeroes, so $[T(v)]_C = [T]_B^C[v]_B$ implies that...

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

If the kernel is trivial, then $T$ is injective. Indeed, one has:
\begin{align*}
T(v) = T(w) & \Rightarrow T(v) - T(w) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow T(v - w) = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow v - w \in\ker(T) = \{0\}\\\\
& \Rightarrow v - w = 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow v =  w
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the Rank-nullity theorem in order to prove the desired result.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is the kernel of $T$ is trivial, if $\mathbf {nul} [T]_B^C =0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to note that by definition, $[T]_{B}^{C} = J_{C}^{-1}TJ_{B}$, where $J_{B} \colon \mathbb{F}^n \to V$ and $J_{C} \colon \mathbb{F}^n \to W$ are the natural isomorphisms given by $J_{B}e_j = b_j$, $J_{C}e_j = c_j$. This easily implies that $[T]_{B}^{C}$ is an isomorphism if and only if $T$ is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately we don't work with those Jordan formats...

Comment: @CalculusLover This is not related to Jordan form at all. $J_B$ is the coordinate map. Given coordinate vector $x \in \mathbb{F}^n$, $J_Bx$ gives the vector in $V$ with coordinates $x$ in basis $B$, i.e. $J_Bx = x_1b_1 + \dots + x_nb_n$.